# Register dynamic resources in C# Web API

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, dropwizard

I'm Java developer and I need to port Dropwizard (+Jersey) application to C#. I found that the best way to create REST Server is to use **ASP.NET Web API**.

Right now my problem is how to register dynamic providers/resources in Web API. In Java I have this code:

```
// in main Dropwizard class that extends Service
@Override
public void run(HelloWorldConfiguration helloWorldConfiguration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    environment.jersey().register(new JacksonProtobufProvider());
    DropwizardResourceConfig rc = environment.jersey().getResourceConfig();
    rc.registerResources(new RestResourceServiceAdapter(...).getResource());
}

// In RestResourceServiceAdapter:
// This method generates dynamic resource 
// serviceCaller is my internal class that describes resource
private  Resource getResource() {
    final Resource.Builder resourceBuilder = Resource.builder();
    resourceBuilder.path(serviceCaller.getServiceName());
    for (MethodDescriptor md : serviceCaller.getRegisteredMethods()) {
        addMethodResource(resourceBuilder, md.getMethodName(), md.getRequestType(), md.getResponseType());
    }
    return resourceBuilder.build();
}
```

How can I register dynamic resources in Web API?